# How to set different themes for inflated layout in a view stub

Tags: android

I have a layout that I'm inflating into a ViewStub. When its within view A, I want to have one set of styles applied to the EditText fields, and when it's within view B, I want to have a different set of styles applied to the EditText fields.

First, is this possible, and second (if so), how would I go about it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm not sure about ViewStubs specifically, but if you wanted to inflate a predefined layout and add it to a ViewGroup you could use a [ContextThemeWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html).

```
View viewOne = View.inflate(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Theme_One), R.layout.my_layout)
View viewTwo = View.inflate(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Theme_Two), R.layout.my_layout)
```